# How to select selective indices base column from matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiple-columns

I have a matrix named `eta` (54×1800). For selecting specific rows and columns typically we use:

```
result = eta(:, 86:90:1800);
```

But here I need to select consecutive **5 columns** `86,87,88,89,90` each having difference `90`. e.g after `86, 87, 88, 89, 90`, I want to get `176, 177, 178, 179, 180`.

I tried this:

```
result=eta(:,[86:90:1800,87:90:1800,88:90:1800,89:90:1800,90:90:1800]);
```

But it does not give the result of consecutive columns.

Comment: Can you please properly format your post? It's hard to read this wall of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first index is `a`(=86), the end of region to extract is `b`(=1800) and the difference is `d`(=90), then you would do:

```
s = a:d:b; % create all start indices
k = cumsum([s; ones(4,numel(s))],1) % compute all consecutive indices
result = eta(:,k(:)); % exctract all indeces using linear index for the column subscript
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mat=rand(54,1800); %your eta matrix
mywish=[86:1:90]; %your wish to select consective columns
for i=1:length(mywish)
    results=mat(:,mywish(i):90:1800) %getting the column interval 90
end
```